# finding equality with subspaces direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

assume that $U_1 \cap U = \{0\}$ and $U_2 \cap U = \{0\}$

$U_1 \oplus U = U_2 \oplus U$?

I thought that it's correct because I could find a counterexample.

Comment: $U=\{0\}$ , $U_1=<(0,1)>$, $U_2=<(1,0)>$

Comment: @Exodd thanks, also do you have any suggestions on how to approach such questions in the future? I didn't thought about U={0} thats why I couldn't find a counterexample

Comment: What is U, U1,U2 and real or complex vector space?

Comment: @DinRevah There are tons of counterexample with $U\ne 0$. For example, take $\{v,w,z\}$ a base of $\mathbb R^3$. Then $U=<v>$, $U_1=<w>$, $U_2=<z>$ works too